# Как сделать чтоб SQL скрипт не исполнялся в PHP(а использовался как простая строка)?

Tags: php, sql, консоль, symfony, terminal

Я пишу консольное приложение на Symfony, и мне надо, чтобы SQL-скрипты не исполнялись и никак не обрабатывались, а просто записывались в файл как строки.

Некоторые скрипты, где нет внутри  частиц 'id', 'user' и так далее работают правильно, но как они появляються, скрипт на выходе выходит другой.

Команды в терминал посылаються так:

```
php app.php script:add <script>
```

Где `<script>` и есть мой скрипт, записанный в двойных кавычках.

Нужно как то экранировать или изолировать скрипт, чтоб он не менялся.

Comment: в одинарных кавычках не подходит? просто в двойных тебе нужно экранировать очень много всего.

Comment: На Symfony лучше запускать `bin/console script:add --sql="<script>"`, а не `php app.php script:add "<script>"`. Напиши пример, который ломает приложение, потому что так не видно, что не экранировано.